# Does the use of $\gamma=\left(1-v^{2}/c^{2}\right)^{-1/2}$ automatically assume a (+ - - - ) metric?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, conventions

In Special Relativity, does the use of $\gamma=\left(1-v^{2}/c^{2}\right)^{-1/2}$
  automatically assume a (+ - - - ) metric convention? For introductory textbooks, the Lorentz factor is is always defined the same. For a spacial velocity v:

$$\gamma=c\left(c^{2}-v^{2}\right)^{-1/2}$$

$$\frac{c}{\gamma}=\sqrt{c^{2}-v^{2}}$$

$$c=\gamma\sqrt{c^{2}-v^{2}}$$

which can be written as the four velocity $U^{\alpha}=\gamma v^{\alpha}$
 (taking $v^{0}=c$
 ):

$$c=\sqrt{U^{\alpha}U_{\alpha}}$$

Which utilizes a (+ - - - ) convention. I thought this was strange since relativistic texts generally use the (-+++) convention. It may lead to confusion

Comment: Huh? You could write that as $c=\sqrt{-U^\alpha U_\alpha}$ with the mostly plus convention.

Comment: @Ocelo7 duh! You're absolutely right, was just a random stupid thought I had! Haha thanks for pointing my foolishness oit

Answer (score 2):

This definition doesn't depend on the metric signature convention. Note that in definition of $\gamma$ the metric doesn't appear anywhere. It is defined purely in terms of "3-vectors" and "3-scalars" measured by particular observer. So it is impossible for metric to appear here explicitly.